# Running GET Requests in the Chrome Console

Tags: google-chrome, npm, get, request, console

I am trying to run GET requests in the Chrome Console. Usually if I'm making a request, I use the request npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```js
const request = require("request")

request("https://example.org/", function(error, response, body) {
  console.log(response)
  console.log(body)
})
```

However, Chrome doesn't let you require. Is there any other way of doing this? Every other way I tried resulted in a error saying it violated a security. Plus, I am trying to run this request in Discord (https://discord.com/). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome console, you can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of request.

A basic fetch request is really simple to set up. Have a look at the following code:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: That would work, but I am trying to run this in Discord (https://discord.com/), which wouldn't work due to it's security.. Have any other solution? Thanks!